# Using pattern matching to return a function

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a function that returns a function based on the input parameter.

```
def myFunction(x: Int): x => Boolean {
  x => if (x < 7) false
       if (x % 2 == 0) false
       else true
}
```

So if x is less than 7 or even false will be returned. Otherwise true is.

How do I write this using pattern matching?

And if it pointless to use pattern matching for Ints, what about something more complex like a list of Ints.

```
def myFunction(myList: List[Int]): x => Boolean {
  // just doing something simple here real life is more complex.
  x => if (myList.size() < 7) false
       else true
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching is useless when dealing with primitive objects.

Other alternative would be :

```
Option(3).map(x => x < 7 || x % 2 == 0).getOrElse(false)
```

But for this simple case, I prefer simple `if/else`.

For your second case, a function returning a partial function based on a `List[Int]` would be:

```
def myFunction(myList: List[Int]): List[Int] => Boolean = {
    case _ :: Nil  if (myList.size < 7) => false
    case _ => true
}
```

Comment: thanks.  What about the more complex scenarios?  Is it possible to use pattern matching?

Comment: In this case pattern matching does not make sense, but if you match directly on integers, the compiler can create a switch/case statement.

Answer (score 0):

I usually pattern match like this. Any expression returns a value - if else and matching should have approximately the same result.

```
  x match{
    case x if x < 7 => false
    case x if (x % 2 == 0) => false
    case _ => true   }
```